# Trying to get this Subroutine to work to populate Pivot Table Data for each set of dates on each line in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting an endless loop for "i". I think it has to do with data types as these are dates and I had to Dim the Start and Finish dates as a Variant in order to get around a type mismatch error. the code is a starting point to populate each date that is a week starting on a Monday in a vertical list for each occurrence where that date falls between the P1Start and P1Finish dates. Right now I just want it to list that date and then I'll add copy paste commands for the rest of the target data and another loop for each Person's name. I  have a bunch of extra variables defined so that I can use them later, not all are being used right now.

Here are some SS of the Sheet that the work is happening on.

[Excel Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYcri.png)

```
`enter code here`Option Explicit

'Constants for Project Information
Const Row_PD = 2  'First Row with Project Dates in Project Info Table
Const Col_PD = 26  'First Column for Project Dates to be used in Sub from "Project Information"
Const PI = "Project Information"

Const Row_DA = 3 'First Row that has a Valid Date for the Array in Timeline


'Constants for Pivot Data
Const C_PD_Col_Start = 1  'First Column for Project Info Table "Pivot Data"
Const C_PD_Row_Start = 2  'First Row with Data in Pivot Data
Const PD = "Pivot Data"


Sub Range_Loop()
'
' Range_Loop Macro
' Populate Pivot Data for each week and Project and Person in Range for Each Phase by the Various Dates
'
Dim rStart As Variant, rFinish As Variant, pStart As Variant, pFinish As Variant, nProj As Integer, TimeR As Range
Dim a As Long, b As Long, c As Long, d As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long, P1Row As Integer, LPRow As Integer, fRng As Range, DRng As String
Dim P1Start As Variant, P1Finish As Variant, P2Start As Variant, P2Finish As Variant, P3Start As Variant, P3Finish As Variant, P4Start As Variant, P4Finish As Variant

Worksheets(PD).Activate

Range("A2:L100000").Clear

Worksheets(PI).Activate

a = 2 'Home Row for Project Data
b = 26 'Home Column For Project Data
i = 2 'Home Row for Pivot Data
c = 27

P1Row = 2
LPRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row

rStart = Cells(4, 1).Value


Do Until a > LPRow
    Do Until b = 31

    P1Start = Cells(a, b).Value
    P1Finish = Cells(a, c).Value

         Do Until rStart > P1Finish

         If rStart < P1Start And rStart > P1Finish Then
         Worksheets(PD).Cells(i, 1).Value = rStart
         Else
         k = 1
         End If

         rStart = rStart + 7
         i = i + 1
         Loop
    rStart = Cells(4, 1).Value
    b = b + 1
    c = c + 1
    Loop
b = 26
c = 27
a = a + 1
Loop
i = 2`enter code here`

'Worksheets(PI).Cells(a, b).Activate
'MsgBox (rFinish)

End Sub
```

Comment: Where's the infinite loop coming?  If I read this correctly, `Do Until rStart > P1Finish` will *always* have `i = 2`.  Even though you do `i = i + 1`, when that loops, you immediately reset it to `i = 2`.

Comment: I actually had it up above before. I noticed that also and reran the sub I'll edit the code and show where the issues is coming in

Comment: Updated it to be a defined variable prior to kicking off any loops and its definitely still looping forever in the lowest level loop. As though rStart is never getting larger than P1Finish. In increments of 7 it should overtake that Value after less than 100 cycles.

Answer (score 0):

I setup spreadsheet per your example and this line (used twice): `rStart = Cells(4, 1).Value` references an empty cell. Tested code and not getting endless loop but don't get any output either.

This line makes no sense `If rStart < P1Start And rStart > P1Finish Then` as it will never be read when rStart is greater than P1Finish because of `Do Until rStart > P1Finish` so it will never be true and the line to output data will never be read. Logic is faulty.

Change the If to: `If rStart < P1Start Then` and you will get output, even if you don't change Cells(4, 1) to Cells(3, 1) although probably should. But is it the output you want?